# How do I make 'i' number of functions in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a for loop with `[i]` number of similar functions in Python:

```
i = int(raw_input())
for i in range (0, i):
  myfunction[i] = str(raw_input())
```

And I'm getting an error that it isn't defined.  So I'm defining it....  How do I define [i] number of similar functions?

Comment: You need to clarify, what is the intent of the functions? If the functions need to do different things, then you still need to write them manually, which makes them more "individual".

Comment: unwind, Thank you.  +1.  The functions set a text value.  The desired result is a variable, variable[i], filled with a string.  Should I edit?

Comment: Do you want myfunction[i] to be a function or a string?

Comment: They're the result of the user inputs.  They're `strings`, but they're the result of functions `raw_input()`[1], `raw_input()`[2]...

Comment: Those are strings, not functions. Do you just want to add strings to a list?

Comment: Yes, but they have to be user-input strings, and they have to be loaded into a variable.  I'm trying to finish the code with `for i in range (0,i) print a+b+c+myvariable[i]+d`.

Comment: lol.  Why does everyone want to close my question?

Comment: @Unwind: The idea is to perform the same operation on different arguments.  For example, if I have a group of 10 `Getter methods` in a `class`, each named `Getter_ObjectName(returns)`, couldn't I just create one function `Getter_$Object[i](returns)`?  And then call them like `Class.Getter_ObjectName(returns)`?  Or should I use an argument: `Class.Getter_Generic(ObjectName, returns)`?

Comment: Anyway, Prez's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set list items by index, try:

```
myfunction = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    myfunction.append(whatever)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'append' is read-only`

Comment: Are you doing `myfunction append = x` instead of `myfunction.append(x)`?

Comment: I was doing `myfunction.append = raw_input()`.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to reference it?  `print myfunction[i, j]`

Comment: Prez, thank you.  You rock. Would you like to see the resulting code?

Comment: This is where I applied your answer (the generalized form, my answer): http://superuser.com/questions/376288/how-do-i-add-input-to-my-macro-to-replace-text-in-notepad

Answer (score 3):

larsmans answer can also be implemented this way:

```
def make_function(x):
    def function(y):
        return x + y
    return function

functions = [make_function(i) for i in xrange(5)]

# prints [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print [f(4) for f in functions]
```

**Updated**

From the edit and all the comments it seems that you want to ask the user for a number N and then ask for N strings and have them put into a list.

```
i = int(raw_input('How many? '))
strings = [raw_input('Enter: ') for j in xrange(i)]
print strings
```

When run:

```
How many? 3
Enter: a
Enter: b
Enter: c
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If the list comprehension seems unreadable to you, here's how you do it without it, with some comments:

```
i = int(raw_input('How many? '))
# create an empty list
strings = []
# run the indented block i times
for j in xrange(i):
    # ask the user for a string and append it to the list
    strings.append(raw_input('Enter: '))
print strings
```

Comment: I see what you mean.  Thank you.  Sorry, prez beat you to it, though.  Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want here, but from all that you said, it appears to me to be simply this:

```
def myfunction(j):
    for i in range(j):
        variable.append(raw_input('Input something: '))
```

I still think this may not be what you want. Correct me if I am wrong, and please be a little clear.

Answer (score 0):

`myfunction[i]` is the i'th element of the list `myfunction`, which you have not already defined; hence the error.

If you want a sequence of functions, you can try something like this:

```
def myfunction(i,x):
    if i==0:
        return sin(x)
    elif i==1:
        return cos(x)
    elif i==2:
        return x**2
    else:
        print 'Index outside range'
        return
```

If you need similar functions that have something to do with `i`, it gets simpler, like this example:

```
def myfunction(i,x):
    return x**i
```

Comment: Lists can certainly contain functions. Try `[map, zip, reduce]`.

Comment: @Abhranil, I didn't thumbs you down, dude.  I think that this defeats the purpose, though.  The idea is to have `i` definitions.  The number of definitions created is defined by the user input for the `i` value.  It shouldn't be coded by hand.  Let me rephrase my question.  I think there was just a communication barrier.

Comment: It's okay, man, no prob. But if you want a class of functions having something to do with `i`, my definition can easily be modified.

Comment: Abhranil, I'm trying to perform `i` similar definitions based on `raw_input()`s.  i results: `i=5; for i in range (0, i) my_result0 = raw_input(); my_result1 = raw_input(); my_result2 = raw_input(); my_result4 = raw_input();`.  There may be a better way of doing this than adding `i` to the end of each variable name, or indexing.  Maybe properties or something.  I don't know for sure.  I'm very much a beginner.